# Flutter named paramter is not defined for Card widget

Tags: flutter, material-ui, flutter-layout, named-parameters, flutter-card

I'm trying to create a reusable Card widget to use in other dart files throughout my app.
I keep getting a *named parameter is not defined* error. What could the problem be here?
Things I've already tried:

- Reinstalling the flutter SDK.
- Running *flutter doctor* throws no issues related to this.
- Running a Dart re-analyse on VS-Code.

card.dart

[image: Errors on line 14, 15 and 16]

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'card.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Card'),
        ),
        body: Card());
  }
}
```

Description of error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the class name differ from Card. Beacuse you already have Card class in dart pakage.

Solution:

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Card(color: Colors.red,));
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! The issue arose because the Card class already exists within Dart and I was trying to use that as a custom class right?